# Conditional distribution of steps of random walk given the sum

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-walks

**Set-up.** Consider a random walk $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $\{ X_i, 1\leq i < \infty \} $
is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mu$, $\mathbb{E}X_1 = 0$. Let $a > 0$.
Given $|S_n| \leq a $, the random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are still identically distributed (because of the invariance under permutations), but they are not independent.

**Question.** Is it always true that the convergence in distribution takes place:

$$
X_1 \Big| \{|S_n| \leq a\} \Rightarrow X_1    \ \ \ \text{ as } n\to \infty \ ? \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

**Some thoughts.** On the left hand side of (1) is the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $\{|S_n| \leq a\}$. For instance if $\mu = \frac 12 \delta _1 + \frac 12\delta _{-1}$, then (1) is not difficult to prove. What about the general case? This question is remotely related to these two questions: [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315016/concentration-of-closed-random-walks) and [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352519/how-often-a-random-walk-with-irrational-increments-is-close-to-0).

**Proof idea (based on Thomas Kojar's comment)** Set $R_n = S_n - X_1$. For a Borel set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$
\mathbb{P} \{ X_1 \in B, -a \leq S_n \leq a \} = 
\mathbb{E} \Big( \mathbf{I}\{ X_1 \in B \}
\mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbf{I}\{ -a - X_1 \leq R_n \leq a - X_1 \} \big| 
X_1 \big]\Big).
$$
Therefore if for all $M > 0$
$$
\sup\limits _{b \in [-M,M]}
\big|\ln \mathbb{P} \{  -a - b \leq R_n \leq a - b \}
 - \ln \mathbb{P} \{  -a  \leq R_n \leq a  \}\big| = 0,
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \   \  (2)
$$
then $\mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbf{I}\{ -a - X_1 \leq R_n \leq a - X_1 \} \big| 
X_1 \big]$ is approximately
$\mathbb{P} \{  -a  \leq R_n \leq a \} $
and (1) follows. Now, (2) is a consequence of  [Stone's local limit theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-36/issue-2/A-Local-Limit-Theorem-for-Nonlattice-Multi-Dimensional-Distribution-Functions/10.1214/aoms/1177700165.full), at least for a wide class of non-lattice distributions $\mu$.

Comment: How about doing it by hand by writing $$S_{n+1}=X_1+R_n$$ and then applying strong law to show that the effect of X1 is negligible in the second event in $$P(X_1>t, -a/n<X_1/n+R_n/n<a/n)\approx P(X_1>t) P( -a/n-c_n<R_n/n<a/n+c_n)+o(g_n)$$ for some $g_n,c_n\to 0$ at least when if we assume that X1 is upper/lower bounded?

Comment: I think you are correct and for a wide class of $\mu$ (1) is going to follow a local limit theorem. I modify the post.

Comment: You also have to assume that $P(|S_n|\le a)\ne0$. Then, I think, this should be true for all zero-mean $\mu$ -- but the proof is probably quite nontrivial.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Indeed, $\mathbb{P}\{|S_n| \leq a \} > 0$ is required at least for large $n$.  If $S_n$ is non-lattice, then $\mathbb{P}\{|S_n| \leq a \} > 0$ follows from the local limit theorem, whereas if $S_n$ is lattice, it has to be aperiodic (or (1) has to be adapted). The local limit theorem holds for a distribution in the domain of attraction of a stable distribution, so it seems to me that at least for those distributions the proof (1) can follow pretty much along the same lines as in the post.

Comment: The real challenge here is to show that this holds for all zero-mean $\mu$ (or maybe to construct a counterexample).